# Does any passport never expire?

Tags: passports, expired

While filling the booking form on Kiwi.com, I noticed that below the passport/ID expiration date there is a box "No expiration" that can be checked.

See screenshot here:

[image: Screenshot of Chrome on Android. A page on kiwi.com is open. There is an unfilled date field labelled "Passport or ID expiration date", and below it an unchecked checkbox labelled "No expiration".]

This made me wonder: Does any passport never expire?

Comment: May be King of UK. He doesn't need a passport, so it technically doesn't have an expiry date.

Comment: I can't find it now, but I believe the paper Greek ID Card didn't expire

Comment: This question seems to be unaware of domestic air travel existence. Domestic travellers do so on very weird documents.

Comment: @AnishSheela Passports that don't exist, of course, never expire.

Comment: Since the first passport conventions of the 1920's, the recommendation has always been that duration of validity of passport be restricted. First 2, then 5 and now 10 years.

Comment: @AnishSheela I doubt the King is booking through Kiwi.com.

Comment: Where I am, all I see is a box followed by "enter image description here"... please describe in words what the picture shows. Yes, you have your question written, but as it is, to me, it would have to be a "low quality question" because there is no reason for asking it that I can see. Please note, I've neither D/V or VtC

Comment: Diplomatic passports?

Comment: They all expire (so far as I am aware) with the death of the bearer.

Comment: Several EU countries formerly issued ID cards that didn't expire.  I believe some of these are still valid; for example Italy is phasing them out, but I don't think the transition is complete.

Comment: @nigel222 Diplomatic passports are often returned after the diplomatic mission has ended.

Comment: The EU/Schengen does not accept foreign passports for entry issued more than 10 years earlier even if their stated expiry date is more than 3 months after the date of entry.  This caused confusion as the UK had issued passports with a validity of for example 10.5 years for some individuals who had renewed their previous passports in advance.

Comment: I don't know about passports, but other ID might not. In the US, Massachusetts used to issue non-driver's ID cards until 2003 that were good until you moved or died. If you still have one, it's still good today. You wouldn't use those for international travel, but for domestic travel, it would still be good until 2025 (or whenever the eternally delayed REALID deadline actually passes).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There are quite a few national ID cards that don't expire in some cases :

- Bulgarian ID card for citizens >= 58 years old
- Icelandic ID card until a photo change is needed (or until 2026 due to EU Regulation imposing a change of ID)
- Former Romanian ID-2 model for citizens >= 55 years old
- Spanish/Slovenian ID for citizens >= 70 years old
- Former Polish ID card for citizens >= 70 years old
- Non-unified Brazillian ID for citizens > 60 years old
- Hong Kong ID for people holding the right of abode in HK
- Malaysia's MyKad seems to be without expiry

Comment: HKID cards don't have an expiry date printed on it, for anyone. Only the date at which the card was applied for. For temporary residents, the date of expiry *of the visa (not the card itself)* is inside the chip.

Comment: That said, the Immigration Department of HK replaces the IDs with new ones every decade or two, effectively invalidating the old ones.

Comment: Standard Arizona (US) driver's licenses and ID cards are good until age 65, but you have to refresh the card with a new photo every 12 years. Real ID came and forced Real ID-compliant versions to expire every 8 years.

Comment: Fantastic! How come you know so many different nations' cards?

Comment: @guest Scavenging through Wikipedia basically

Comment: @NicolasFormichella Oh, I was hoping the answer was "I collect them"

Comment: *Former Polish ID card* - this is also true for the new ones (credit card sized). I found out when a friend's parent was trying to use it in a French system and the system was not ready for a EU document to not have an expiration date...

Comment: Singapore NRIC (National Registration Identity Card) cards don't expire; they are issued to citizens and Permanent Residents. They do need to be re-registered at age 30 and 55 (to update the photo)

Comment: And various European ID cards are valid 5 years after *expiration*. So the real expiration date is 15 years.

Answer (score 48):

Frame challenge: The point is not that the document never expires, it's just it does not have expiration date *printed on it* anywhere, so it is not a part of document data.

Obvious examples: Russian domestic passports do need to be replaced when you turn 18 and 45 years old, but that date is not printed anywhere in the passport and is flexible (expired passport is still valid and needs to be replaced after the fact).

Russian birth certificates never expire, but they stop being IDs when you come of age. However, that date is never printed in the document. As soon as the kid gets their domestic passport they stop using birth certificate as an ID.

These are primary documents on which Russian citizens fly domestically and they are specified with no expiry date.

Comment: Indeed, my HKID card doesn't have an expiry date per se, ie printed on the card, although the chip inside HKID cards have an expiry date for temporary residents. And the HK government has launched a few years ago an ID card renewal program for everybody, spanning a few years (every few months they call up a new series of year of birth).

Comment: "Russian birth certificates never expire, but they stop being IDs when you come of age." As a programmer, I would say that the expiration date is printed, since it can be easily calculated from the birth date and the (common) knowledge of the age of expiration.

Comment: @SJuan76 In fact there were misguided booking forms around ther were demanding expiry date to be set. So people entered "10 years from now" there, or 2099-12-31, or actually did the calculations that you describe. Needless to say it's all having the same credibility since *it's not printed on the piece of paper*.